# It has any possible to create a thread to send request to server in background

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I want to write a function that can send request to server continuously in background. But I don't know to use thread in React Native. Can you give me some and suggestions.and it is best don't use native codes.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is single-threaded, so you can't manage/create threads.
You can read about the threading model [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop).

The interesting part for you is that network requests in javascript don't pause your thread. They always run in the background and will resume work on the JS thread once they are completed.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I think there are two ways to solve the problem.The first is that I will use the method of asynchronous. Another, I need use native code to solve it. I want to know the first way whether has an effect on performance.

Answer (score -1):

**@RichardSleet** you can do that with help of [webworkers](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp)

A web worker is a JavaScript that runs in the background, independently of other scripts, without affecting the performance of the page
so when you create new worker

each worker will have whole new **CONTEXT**

**Example : You can run 10 for loops parallely with webworkers**

Comment: Webworkers are not available in react native, check out the tags in the question.

Comment: I agree with @Moti Azu and I solve problem by creating the thread in native part.